# Search particular document id in all available indices of Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Is there any possibility where we can search a particular document id in all available indices. `/_all/_search/` returns all documents but I tried it as `/_all/_search/?q=<MYID>` or
 `/_all/_search/_id/<MYID>`

but I'm not getting any documents.

If Elasticsearch does not support this, how will we achieve this task ? The use case is centralized log system based on Logstash and Elasticsearch, having multiple indices of different running services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `terms` query for this. Use `_all` to search on all indexes.Please refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-api-all-ex)

here is the request I used

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_all/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [
        "4ea288f192e2c8b6deb3cee00d7b873b",
        "dcc2b9c4fb6d14b2d41dbc5fee801af3"
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

`_id` is the id of the document

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multi get](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html) api
You will need to pass the index name , it won't work on all indices

```
GET /_mget
{
    "docs" : [
        {
            "_index" : "index1",
            "_id" : "1"
        },
        {
            "_index" : "index2",
            "_id" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
```